# Ubuntu will only start if I have an external monitor plugged in

Tags: boot, dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display

I installed ubuntu from a live USB as dual boot alongside windows on a Razer Blade laptop.
During installation an external monitor was plugged in the laptop.
Now, the external monitor needs to be plugged in on Ubuntu start, otherwise Ubuntu crashes right after I enter my login password.
Once Ubuntu is started I can use it normally, but if I click on the icon for system settings, it crashes.
Also I can't turn off the computer from the top right menu, I can only turn it off by pressing on the power button for twenty seconds.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which doesn't require reinstallation. It works for ubuntu 20.04.

Steps:

1. `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. Uncommment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to disable graphical terminal.
3. `sudo update-grub`

Original link: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/v0ff1r/ubuntu_2204_server_wont_boot_without_hdmi_plugged/

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reinstall 16.04 LTS, deactivate the nouveau driver by updating grub with "nouveau.modeset=0", then use a USB-C to HDMI dongle to plug in the external monitor in the thunderbolt port instead of the HDMI port.